# Shipping options depending on cart weight

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a Wordpress site that uses Woocommerce.
I found this piece of code that allows to set the freight shipping option based on weight but I need to have prices :
- from 0 to 2 kg = 10 €
- then 2 kg to 5 kg = 15 €
- then 5kg to 10 kg = 20 €
and so on till 20 kg.
Above 20 kg it's only on demand.
Here is the code I tried to use and modify :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping', 9999, 2 );

function bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping( $rates, $package ) {

     if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() < 2 ) {

         if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:32'] ) ) unset( $rates['flat_rate:32'], $rates['flat_rate:32'] );

     } elseif ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() < 5 ) {

         if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:32'] ) ) unset( $rates['flat_rate:32'], $rates['flat_rate:33'] );

     } elseif ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() < 10 ) {

         if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:32'] ) ) unset( $rates['flat_rate:32'], $rates['flat_rate:34'] );

     } elseif ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() < 15 ) {

         if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:32'] ) ) unset( $rates['flat_rate:32'], $rates['flat_rate:35'] );

      } elseif ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() < 20 ) {

         if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:32'] ) ) unset( $rates['flat_rate:32'], $rates['flat_rate:36'] );

     }

     return $rates;

}
```

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

I did find a better piece of code that works for the prices.
Now I have only the issue with above 20 kg...How to inform "on demand" instead of the price ?
Best,
David